# How I am gonna solve req.body.password undefined in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, mern

Hello devs I am building an API using EXPRESS.JS AND MongoDB and performing some tests with postman. But I am getting the req. body. password field is undefined when I try to parse it using postman however I am able to parse the name and the email but the password is undefined.
I need help !

bellow are my files

This is my userController.js file

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const User = require('../models/userModel');


// @Desc Register New User
// @Routes POST /api/users
// @Access Public
const userRegister = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const {name, email, password} = req.body;
  res.json({name: `${name}`, email: `${email}`, password: `${password}`});

  if (!name || !email) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error('Please Enter valid Inputs');
  }
  res.json({ message: 'User Register' });
});

// @Desc Authenticate User
// @Routes POST /api/users/login
// @Access Public
const userLogin = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'User Login' });
});

// @Desc User Data
// @Routes POST /api/users/member
// @Access Public
const userMember = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'User Member' });
});

// @Desc User Data
// @Routes GET /api/users
// @Access Public
const userProfile = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'User Profile' });
});

module.exports = {
  userRegister,
  userLogin,
  userMember,
  userProfile,
};
```

And here is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const colors = require('colors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const { errorHandler } = require('./middleware/errorMiddleware');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

connectDB();

const app = express();

// Middleware

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Routes
const postRoute = require('./routes/postRoutes');
const userRoute = require('./routes/userRoutes');

app.use('/api/posts', postRoute);
app.use('/api/users', userRoute);

app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`));
```

The route file is

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// import User controllers
const {
  userRegister,
  userLogin,
  userMember,
  userProfile,
} = require('../controllers/userController');

router.route('/').post(userRegister);
router.route('/member').post(userMember);
router.route('/login').post(userLogin);
router.route('/profile').get(userProfile);
module.exports = router;
```

Here is the userModel.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    profilePicture: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// Exporting the schema
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And finally, this is the output from POSTMAN

[image: POSTMAN REQ.BODY.PASSWORD-UNDEFINED]

Comment: Could you show us the method in which you parse the request ? It would be easier to help you with this

Comment: it's a post method as shown in the postman picture

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your request handler was in your first code block. Have you tried to look at the req.body content using a debugger ?

Comment: Your api should throw an error because it calls `res.json` twice. Try to restart your server and try again.

Comment: Looking into the req.body I got this : { name: 'Djallo', email: 'dj@gmail.com', 'password ': '145236789' }

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it just by changing this

```
const {name, email, password} = req.body;
```

to

```
const {name, email, pass} = req.body;
```

Updating `password` to `pass`

This change makes it work for me

[image: postman-req.body.password]

Thank you so much for your support

> `Blockquote`